# why don't my authorization header need Bearer?

Tags: linux, http, curl, https, rcurl

I am using curl command to fetch the manifest file of the singularity image as below

**curl -H "Authorization :"**

and it is working fine for me and i am able to fetch the manifest file andi it is working without appending Bearer

but when I append Bearer string in the Authorization header as below

**curl -H "Authorization : Bearer "**

curl command is failing to fetch the manifest

but actually it should work when we appended Bearer to Authorization header and it should fail when we dont append Bearer to Authorization header right

why is this happening so and where am i going wrong?

Comment: The header is just that: A Header. How the server parses and handles that header is depending on the implementaion. To give further insights one would need to know what service/website you talk to.

Comment: Additionally: Bearer is just a specific way of authorization, namely the bearer token auth scheme. there are quite a few other ways to do it, e.g. basic or digiest (or one of the other trillions of ways of doing that)